# Varargs in thymeleaf @ModelAttribute?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I want to pass multiple variable parameters (including none) for a `@ModelAttribute` evaluation from html thymeleaf page to a method:

```
//provide 0 or X params
@ModelAttribute("url")
public String url(String... params) {
    return "generatedurl";
}
```

The following thymeleaf statements should be possible:

```
th:href="@{${url()}"
th:href="@{${url('page')}}"
th:href="@{${url('page', 'sort')}}"
```

But it does not work. Why?

Comment: How about adding a right curly bracket to enclose `@{}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround: add the enclosing class as a model parameter, and call the method on this param from thymeleaf:

```
@Controller
public class PageController {
    @GetMapping
    public String persons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("util", this);
        return "persons";
    }

    public String url(String... params) {
        //evaluate...
        return "generatedurl";
    }
}
```

It's then possible to access the methods as normal:

```
th:href="@{${url()}"
th:href="@{${url('page')}}"
th:href="@{${url('page', 'sort')}}"
```

Only drawback is of course having to add the class to the model explicit.

Another choice would be to initialize the model with the parameter permutations that I need. But that's less flexible:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void init(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("plainUrl", ...);
    model.addAttribute("pageUrl", ...);
    model.addAttribute("pageSizeUrl", ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ModelAttribute` is used to bind common objects to the model.

You are returning a String `generatedurl` every time from your method `url()` annotated with `@ModelAttribute`. So in your Thymleaf view every time yo do `${url}` you get `generatedurl`.

One workaround for your problem could be this

```
@ModelAttribute("url")
public void url(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("url","YOUR_URL");
    model.addAttribute("sort","age");
}
```

Comment: No. I want to pass 0-2 parameters to the `@ModelAttribute` method. In my example these 2 parameters have the value `"page"` and `"sort"`.

Comment: Why are you calling that method with two params? And how are you planning to actually call it?

Comment: As written above, I plan to call it with variable number of arguments. Like `url()`, `url('page', 'size')`, etc.

Comment: I believe methods annotated with `@ModelAttribute` are called by the spring container. It is just there to add certain objects to your model!!